# Side by side divs unexplained margins

Tags: html, css

I have  two div elements side by side, but for some reason there is a margin between them of a few pixels.

I cannot see why as there is no inheritance of a margin on these divs according to Chrome's dev tools.

This is the output i get:

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
<div class="menu_wrap center">
     <div class="row">
         <div style="width:200px;" class="display vdisplay brdr">Name</div>
         <div style="width:100px;" class="display vdisplay brdr">Surname</div>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

My CSS including the possible inheritance attributes is:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{   
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
.wrap{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:900px;
    background-color:#adadad;
    padding-top:30px;
}
.center{
  margin:0 auto;  
}
.display{
  display:inline-block;
}
.vdisplay{
   vertical-align:top;
}
.menu_wrap{
   width:850px;
}
.row{       
  margin-bottom:3px;
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100%;
}
.brdr{
   border:1px solid black;
}
```

I've included all the related elements that they could possibly inherit - I still don't know why this gap persists! Its driving me crazy!

Any one able to explain where this gap is coming from ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a bit of a strange behaviour when it comes to setting elements in the same line in HTML. There's a really good article about this problem and some solutions for it here:

http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

But I will give you the quick summary:

Basically, any elements that are placed on the same line will always have a space inbetween them (about 5px). This space isn't caused by margin, or padding.. it's literally just a space. In that article, the author equated it to having spaces inbetween words, which I think is probably the best way to think of it.

As for solutions, I usually find the best one is to not put any line breaks in-between the elements in your code. Obviously that can lead to things being a bit messy, but you can get around that by doing something like this:

```
<div style="width:200px;" class="display vdisplay brdr">Name
</div><div style="width:100px;" class="display vdisplay brdr">Surname</div>
```

Where the closing tag for the previous element is on the same line as the opening for the next.

Other options include setting a negative margin to counteract the space, or using `float` instead, among other things. I find the CSS solutions to be a bit hacky though, and I'd rather prevent the problem rather than try to fight it back.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `font-size: 0;` on the container will fix this issue.